# rounded corners of an arrow in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows, rounded-corners

I have an arrow that looks like in this:

```
    \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}        
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily\normalsize}}}
    
    \tikzstyle{textbox} = [rectangle, minimum width = 3.2cm, minimum height = 1cm, rounded corners = 1pt, line width = 1pt, draw = black, align = center]
    \tikzstyle{arrow}   = [solid, line width = 9pt, -{Triangle[width = 18pt, length = 12pt]}, color = black, shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt]
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm and 1cm, outer sep = 0, inner sep = 0]
                
            \node [textbox]                  (box1) {box1};
            \node [textbox, right = of box1] (box2) {box2};
            \draw [arrow] (box1) -- (box2);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: arrow between boxes]

My Goal is to round all the corners of the arrow by 1pt like I am doing it with the textboxes. I already tried line cap and rounded corners but it is not working. How am I able to round all the corners of the arrow head and also the of the line cap by 1pt?

Comment: Some arrowheads support a [round] option; e.g. Latex[round]

Comment: Arrow head `round` is short for `line cap=round, line join=round`, so I would think that *all* arrow heads support that option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  \documentclass[tikz]{standalone}        
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily\normalsize}}}
    
    \tikzstyle{textbox} = [rectangle, minimum width = 3.2cm, minimum height = 1cm, rounded corners = 1pt, line width = 1pt, draw = black, align = center]
    \tikzstyle{arrow}   = [solid, line width = 9pt, -{Triangle[width = 18pt, length = 12pt, round, line width=1pt]}, color = black, shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt]
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm and 1cm, outer sep = 0, inner sep = 0]
                
            \node [textbox]                  (box1) {box1};
            \node [textbox, right = of box1] (box2) {box2};
            \draw [arrow] (box1) -- (box2);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Rounded arrow]

To make the left end rounded, you can add a rounded `Square` to the end like this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}        
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily\normalsize}}}
    
    \tikzstyle{textbox} = [rectangle, minimum width = 3.2cm, minimum height = 1cm, rounded corners = 1pt, line width = 1pt, draw = black, align = center]
    \tikzstyle{arrow}   = [solid, line width = 9pt, {Square[round, line width=1pt, length= 2pt, width=9pt]}-{Triangle[width = 18pt, length = 12pt, round, line width=1pt]}, color = black, shorten >= 3pt, shorten <= 3pt]
    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm and 1cm, outer sep = 0, inner sep = 0]
                
            \node [textbox]                  (box1) {box1};
            \node [textbox, right = of box1] (box2) {box2};
            \draw [arrow] (box1) -- (box2);
            
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Rounded arrow in both ends]

An other way to do this would be not to use an arrow at all, but to use a `single arrow` node shape.

**Edit:**

Using a `single arrow` node also rounds the inner corners, but of course it does not extend as a normal draw arrow:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}        
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes, arrows.meta, positioning, shapes.arrows}
    \tikzset{every picture/.style={/utils/exec={\sffamily\normalsize}}}
    \tikzstyle{textbox} = [rectangle, minimum width = 3.2cm, minimum height = 1cm, rounded corners = 1pt, line width = 1pt, draw = black, align = center]    
    \begin{document}
        \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 2cm and 1cm, outer sep = 0, inner sep = 0]            
            \node [textbox]                  (box1) {box1};
            \node [textbox, right = of box1] (box2) {box2};
            \path (box1) -- (box2) node[midway, xshift= -2pt, draw, single arrow, minimum height=0.8cm, minimum width=0.7cm, single arrow head extend=0.01cm, single arrow tip angle=75,rounded corners=1pt, fill]{};
        \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

[image: Rounded arrow including inner corners]

Comment: this is an amazing answer, thank you! 1 additional question regarding your single arrow code answer. If I remove `single arrow head extend=0.01cm` in the single arrow node I only get a really thin line and `minimum height` is not working. Why is this happening?

Comment: I must admit that I do not understand `single arrow head extend=0.01cm` - it was found by trail and error. In the manual it is defined on page 811. I expect it is a bug - it makes no sense to set it so small.